# Reporting service indicator shows wrong color

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I will start with a picture (I know it's a bit difficult to see):

[image]

As you can see in the report I have three groups:

1. Organization level 1 - with some grade and indicator
2. Second group grouped by the entity type (person of organization) and each one has an average grade with indicator
3. The third section is a list of persons of organization with their grades and indicators

The indicators are set follows:
[image: Indicator Set]

The problem is that sometimes the indicator shows the color *yellow* when the grade is 100 (the indicator should show the color green).

I have checked the following:

1. The grade that returns is 100 but the indicator still shows the color yellow
2. I have tried to create c color expression and the result was the same.

I have started to think that this is a bug of Report builder 3 / Reporting services

Comment: You do Avg(Grade) have you checked your Grade values? Do they match?

Comment: Yes I have checked it and they match...

Comment: Its working for me. only thing i have done diffrent is 
RED 0 - 60 
Yello 60.01 - 85 
Green 85.01-100

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions.

- Can you add decimals to the output to see if the yellow 100 is over 100? As these are averages this may effect the upper limit.
- Also try putting the colours in order of green to red.

**Edit:**

Something doesn't match up in your report and / or data as the green "56" acording to tat value should be red, and some of the yellows are to be red.

- You need to check the value you print next to the traffic light as these values are not in any way reflective of the vaues you are getting out for the indicators.
- Also check the data type on the `grade` field or may be add a convert funcrtion, say `cint()` to your expression.

Comment: In addition I suggest to try re-casting the data to INT, and also try to change the green bounds to 85 to 1000 (just to varefy what @glh propused)

Comment: I have tried it all and the problem still happening... just to clarified I have two groups in the table I don't know if it relevent

Answer (score 0):

Your fields should be 0 to .60, .60 to .85, .85 to 1 as it looks like the field you are basing this on is an avg.

Answer (score -2):

You can give a try by Changing the range for the yellow and green as

Yellow: 61 to 85
Green : 86 to 100

Comment: This does not effect the result and infact removes the values between 85 and 86. See [indicators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633651.aspx#SequenceIndicatorStates)

Comment: @Hiten004 - I think you'll find 100.01 is greater than 100.001 leaving values between 100.001 and 100.01 with no designation.

Comment: @Hiten004 – since the user has not mentioned anything about decimal. So you can’t be very much sure about data type.

Comment: @glh – what will effect and what not. It can be answered better by Interrogator only and you are not Interrogator. Because Interrogator is a person who has only better understanding about his/her requirement.

Comment: In general, giving a negative marking to anyone’s thought is not a good way. We all are here to represent our ideas. Not for criticizing  anyone’s thought.